# Basic string manipulation from filenames in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a some file names in bash that I have acquired with

```
$ ones=$(find SRR*pass*1*.fq)
$ echo $ones

SRR6301033_pass_1_trimmed.fq
SRR6301034_pass_1_trimmed.fq
SRR6301037_pass_1_trimmed.fq
...
```

I then converted into an array so I can iterate over this list and perform some operations with filenames:

```
# convert to array
$ ones=(${ones// / })
```

and the iteration:

```
for i in $ones; 
do
  fle=$(basename $i) 
  out=$(echo $fle | grep -Po '(SRR\d*)')
  echo "quants/$out.quant"
done
```

which produces:

```
quants/SRR6301033
SRR6301034
...
...
SRR6301220
SRR6301221.quant
```

However I want this:

```
quants/SRR6301033.quant
quants/SRR6301034.quant
...
...
quants/SRR6301220.quant
quants/SRR6301221.quant
```

Could somebody explain why what I'm doing doesn't work and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want this be done this complicated? You can get rid of all the unnecessary roundabouts and just use a for loop and built-in parameter expansion techniques to get this done.

```
# Initialize an empty indexed array
array=()

# Start a loop over files ending with '.fq' and if there are no such files
# the *.fq would be un-expanded and checking it against '-f' would fail and
# in-turn would cause the loop to break out 

for file in *.fq; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    # Get the part of filename after the last '/' ( same as basename )
    bName="${file##*/}"
    # Remove the part after '.' (removing extension)
    woExt="${bName%%.*}"
    # In the resulting string, remove the part after first '_'
    onlyFir="${woExt%%_*}"
    # Append the result to the array, prefixing/suffixing strings 'quant'
    array+=( quants/"$onlyFir".quant )
done
```

Now print the array to see the result

```
for entry in "${array[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$entry"
done
```

---

Ways your attempt could fail

1. With `ones=$(find SRR*pass*1*.fq)` you are storing the results in a *variable* and not in an *array*. A variable has no way to distinguish if the contents are a list or a single string separated by spaces
2. With `echo $ones` i.e. an unquoted expansion, the string content is subject to word splitting. You might not see a difference as long as you have filenames with spaces, having one might let you interpret parts of the filename as different files
3. The part `${ones// / }` makes no-sense in converting the string to an array as  the attempt to use an unquoted variable `$ones` itself would be erroneous
4. `for i in $ones;` would be error prone for the said reasons above, the filenames with spaces could be interpreted as separated files instead of one.

Comment: Simply inexperienced with bash I guess - my aim is to pass the list with two others like it (one of which is in `$ones`) element-wise to a program. This is very helpful! Thanks